# didMoveToParentViewController called twice

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I made a simple test to learn more about contained view controller.
I have a view controller where I added/removed a view controller using two buttons' action:

```
- (IBAction)myInfoAddAction:(id)sender {
    profileViewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController: profileViewController];
    UIView *__view = profileViewController.view;
    [self.view addSubview: __view];
    [profileViewController didMoveToParentViewController: self];
}

- (IBAction)myInfoRemoveAction:(id)sender {
    [profileViewController willMoveToParentViewController: nil];
    [profileViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [profileViewController removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

Class `ProfileViewController` extends `UIViewController` and override `willMoveToParentViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` methods

```
-( void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [super willMoveToParentViewController: parent];
    NSLog(@"willMoveToParentViewController -> %@", self);
}

-( void) didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent
{
    [super didMoveToParentViewController: parent];
    NSLog(@"didMoveToParentViewController -> %@", self);
}

-( void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear -> %@", self);
}

-( void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidDisappear -> %@", self);
}
```

When I add view controller, I got the following logs:

```
willMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
viewWillAppear -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
didMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
didMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
```

When I remove view controller:

```
willMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
didMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
viewDidDisappear -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
didMoveToParentViewController -> <ProfileViewController: 0x8c52ea0>
```

I'd like to know Why `didMoveToParentViewController` is invoked twice?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you log the parent as well? I suspect that it's `nil` on one of those cases to indicate that you are leaving the previous controller.

Comment: It is pretty strange. Maybe you should put a breakpoint into the methods and watch the stack trace. However, I think the 2nd call is triggered by the `addSubview` and `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: I ran into the same issue recently. Calling **removeFromParentViewController** before **removeFromSuperview** seems to have fixed the issue for me. This is odd seeing that the Apple examples configure it like you have. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW3

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same issue as well. Furthermore, I found that when I added the child view controller during viewDidLoad, I only had one message. I fixed it by removing the call to `[super didMoveToParentViewController:]`. I think the issue has to do with adding child view controllers while in the callback from a button, but I'm not sure why this should cause an issue.

Comment: This works. I can't imagine it's the correct solution, but I think you're on to something with adding child view controllers from callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

One can filter out repeated system calls of `didMoveToParentViewController` by checking current parent view controller. In this case we can use super call as it should be.

```
- (void)didMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    [super didMoveToParentViewController:parent];

    if (parent == nil && self.parentViewController == nil) return;
    if (parent != nil && self.parentViewController == parent) return;

    // From here any code called once
}
```

Comment: This won't work for `didMove` because by the time this method is called the `self.parent` would be equal to the `didMoveTo: parent`.
It would work for `willMove` though because then the `parent` parameter would be newer than the `self.parent` field.

Answer (score -1):

you must call the super function of 'viewWillAppear' and 'viewDidDisappear'